# Find all solutions of ${\frac {1} {x} } + {\frac {1} {y} } +{\frac {1} {z}}=1$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all solutions of  ${\frac {1} {x} } + {\frac {1} {y} } +{\frac {1} {z}}=1$ , where $x,y,z$ are positive integers.

Found ten solutions $(x,y,z)$ as ${(3,3,3),(2,4,4),(4,2,4),(4,4,2),(2,3,6),(2,6,3),(3,6,2),(3,2,6),(6,2,3),(6,3,2)}$.  Are these the only 10 solutions?
First, none of $x$, $y$ or $z$ can be $1$ ($x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive integers)

If I let $x=2$, then finding all solutions to $1/y+1/z = 1/2$    leads to $(4,4), (3,6)$ and $(6,3)$ which gives me $(x,y,z)$ as $(2,4,4), (2,3,6), (2,6,3)$ but this also means $(4,4,2), (4,2,4), (3,2,6), (3,6,2), (6,2,3), (6,3,2)$ are all valid triples for this equation.
If I let $x=3$, the only different values of $y$ and $z$ are $(3,3)$
How do I prove these are the only ten solutions? (without using any programming)

Known result:  If we denote $d(n^2)$ as the number of divisors of $n^2$, then the number of solutions of ${\frac {1} {x} }+{\frac {1} {y} } = {\frac {1} {n} }$   =  $d(n^2)$  (For positive $x$, $y$)

For ${\frac {1} {x} } + {\frac {1} {y} } +{\frac {1} {z}}=1$

$z = \frac{xy}{y(x-1)-x}$ where $xy \neq 0$
What happens after that?

Question is: how do we sho there are the only ten solutions?  I'm not asking for a solution.

Assuming $x \le y \le z$

$1 \le y \le \frac{xy}{y(x-1)-x}$

$\Longrightarrow 1 \le x \le y \le \frac{2x}{x-1} $

Got the answer.  I'll probably call @mathlove's answer. (Any additional answers I'll view later)
Liked @user44197 answer.

Comment: And by extension, how many solutions are there for $n$ variables to the equation $\frac 1{x_1}+\frac 1{x_2}+\frac 1{x_3}+\cdots+\frac 1{x_n}=1$ where $\forall i,x_i\in\Bbb Z^+$...

Comment: This equation Markov. Formulas in General gives a rational decision.  Integers are a special case of the solutions of this equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the only possible solution. Proof is as follows:

Suppose that $d = gcd(x,y)$ and $x=d ~ x0$, $y=d ~y_0$ where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are co-prime.
Substituting in the original equation we get
$$ 1/x + 1/y + 1/z=1 \Rightarrow -d\,x_0\,y_0\,z+y_0\,z+x_0\,z+d\,x_0\,y_0 =0$$
Solving for $d$:
$$d=\frac{\left( y_0+x_0\right) \,z}{x_0\,y_0\,\left( z-1\right) }$$
Since $x_0$ and $y_0$ are co-prime, for $d$ to be an integer, $x_0\,y_0$ should divide $z$.
Hence we require
$$ z= k ~x_0 ~y_0$$
Substituting in the equation for $d$ and solving for $k$:
$$ k=\frac{d}{d\,x_0\,y_0-y_0-x_0}$$
This shows that $d$ is a multiple of $k$. Let
$$ d= \mu k$$. Then
$$k=\frac{k\,\mu}{k\,\mu\,x_0\,y_0-y_0-x_0}$$
Solving for $k$:
$$k=\frac{1}{x_0\,y_0}+\frac{1}{\mu\,y_0}+\frac{1}{\mu\,x_0}$$
This implies that $1 \le x_0 \le 3$, $1 \le y_0 \le 3$, $1 \le \mu\le 3$

It is possible to eliminate some of the 27 possible values since $k$ has to be an integers this will result in 12 possible values for $(x_0,y_0,\mu)$ and two of the solutions are repetitions giving the 10 solutions mentioned in the problem.

Comment: Thanks @user44197. I got 10 possible values for which k is integer actually by your approach. $(x_0,y_0,\mu)$ as ${(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(2,1,1),(2,3,1),(3,2,1),(1,1,2),(1,3,2),(3,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,1,3)}$

Comment: Thanks for validating. Actually, by looking at divisibility, one can reduce the search to less than 27 possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

We may as well assume $x\le y\le z$ (and then count rearrangements of the variables as appropriate).  The smallest variable, $x$, cannot be greater than $3$ (or else $1/x+1/y+1/z\lt1/3+1/3+1/3=1$), nor can it be equal to $1$ (or else $1/x+1/y+1/z=1+1/y+1/z\gt1$).  So either $x=2$ or $x=3$.

If $x=3$, then $y=z=3$ as well (for the same reason as before), which gives the solution $(x,y,z)=(3,3,3)$.

If $x=2$, then $1/2+1/y+1/z=1$ implies

$${1\over2}={1\over y}+{1\over z}$$

Applying the inequality $y\le z$ to this equation, we see that $y$ must be greater than $2$ but cannot be greater than $4$, so $y=3$ or $y=4$.  Each of these gives a solution, $(x,y,z)=(2,3,6)$ and $(2,4,4)$.

Counting rearrangements, we get the OP's $10$ solutions and no others.

Comment: Just to elaborate on a point, for the case where $x=2$: if $y$ satisfies $y>4$ then as $z>y$, it will follow that $\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}<1/2$ if $y>4$. So there is no way $1/2+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$ could be an integer. So then $y$ must be either $3,4$.

Comment: And if one is willing to settle for $1/x+1/y+1/z$ *integral* [instead of the stricter condition of $=1$] then for the case where $x=1$, note that $y$ cannot be greater than $2$ [otherwise, as $z \ge y$, it would follow that both $y,z \ge 3$ and so $1/y+1/z \le 2/3$]. But $x=1,y=2,z=2$ works.

Answer (score 5):

HINT : You may suppose that $1\le x\le y\le z.$ This will make it easier to find the solutions.

Comment: they have to be less than 1 isn't it?  How can x,y,z be greater than 1?

Comment: What? you mean $x\lt 1$? Notice if $x\lt 1$, then $1/x\gt 1$. This means there is no solution of your equation.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake (I can't believe I said that - looks so stupid of me)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Deduce that none of $x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}$ exceeds $7$. This can be done by *mathlove*'s hint above.

Additionally, you can show that there is only one $(a, 2, 2)$-tuple and thus use $(a, 2, 3)$ to bound the solutions.

Comment: But some solutions like (2,3,6) (3,2,6) does not say none should exceed 5

Comment: You probably mean cannot exceed 6

Comment: So basically you are same thing as @mathlove

Comment: If you edit your answer, make a comment in this chain of question for some users who might look at this later

Answer (score 0):

There are 14 possible answers up to order for the 4-term analog of this problem.

2,3,7,42

2,3,8,24

2,3,9,18

2,3,10,15

2,3,12,12

2,4,5,20

2,4,6,12

2,4,8,8

2,5,5,10

2,6,6,6

3,3,4,12

3,3,6,6

3,4,4,6

4,4,4,4

Comment: pls format your post