# Find all solutions of the equation $1/a+1/b+1/c=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions of the equation $1/a+1/b+1/c=1$ .

The above question does not mention whether the solutions should over $\mathbb{R} ,\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb {Q}$ .

However , I am assuming all integer solutions. Now,the solution given in the book is :

> there are three families of solutions $(1,a,-a),(b,1,-b),(c,-c,1)$ where $a,b,c$ are arbitary integers . And there are three more solutions $(1,2,3),(2,4,4),(3,3,3)$. If all numbers are positive atleast one of them is not greater than $2$ or they all are equal to $3$. If one of the numbers say $a$ is negative then $1/b+1/c>1$ and this means either $b$ or $c$ is equal to $1$.

I am not getting how they are drawing up the conclusion "If all numbers are positive atleast one of them is not greater than $2$ or they all are equal to $3$. If one of the numbers say $a$ is negative then $1/b+1/c>1$ and this means either $b$ or $c$ is equal to $1$. "...I am not getting the idea behind the solution....

Firstly, if $x,y,z\leq 1$ then , $1/x+1/y+1/z\geq 3$ , which is not and if $x,y,z\geq 1$ then $1/x+1/y+1/z\leq 3$ ...This can be a valid condition

Now, how to get all the solutions after this...

EDIT: There are certain old threads which I see has posted the solution ...but I feel something a bit off about those solutions ...They take in consideration the gcd of the numbers and then apply some inequality which looks a bit off ...I mean the inequalities presented there are simply concluded without any proof ....Furthermore, those solutions   are not given in a "good way"...

1. One of the solutions given probably one of detailed one or maybe the only detailed one in the thread  is as follows:
   Suppose that $d = gcd(x,y)$ and $x=d ~ x0$, $y=d ~y_0$ where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are co-prime.
   Substituting in the original equation we get
   $$ 1/x + 1/y + 1/z=1 \Rightarrow -d\,x_0\,y_0\,z+y_0\,z+x_0\,z+d\,x_0\,y_0 =0$$
   Solving for $d$:
   $$d=\frac{\left( y_0+x_0\right) \,z}{x_0\,y_0\,\left( z-1\right) }$$
   Since $x_0$ and $y_0$ are co-prime, for $d$ to be an integer, $x_0\,y_0$ should divide $z$.
   Hence we require
   $$ z= k ~x_0 ~y_0$$
   Substituting in the equation for $d$ and solving for $k$:
   $$ k=\frac{d}{d\,x_0\,y_0-y_0-x_0}$$
   This shows that $d$ is a multiple of $k$. Let
   $$ d= \mu k$$. Then
   $$k=\frac{k\,\mu}{k\,\mu\,x_0\,y_0-y_0-x_0}$$
   Solving for $k$:
   $$k=\frac{1}{x_0\,y_0}+\frac{1}{\mu\,y_0}+\frac{1}{\mu\,x_0}$$
   This implies that $1 \le x_0 \le 3$, $1 \le y_0 \le 3$, $1 \le \mu\le 3$

It is possible to eliminate some of the 27 possible values since $k$ has to be an integers this will result in 12 possible values for $(x_0,y_0,\mu)$ and two of the solutions are repetitions giving the 10 solutions mentioned in the problem.

Now, how does they even arrive at the original equation given as $ 1/x + 1/y + 1/z=1 \Rightarrow -d\,x_0\,y_0\,z+y_0\,z+x_0\,z+d\,x_0\,y_0 =0$ ...I do get the one asking the question in that link of this site is not asking for a solution but asking the users whether that solution is complete or not...But I do want to know how to do this?

So the issue is not quite resolved...

The solution given in my book also utilises some inequalities but how does it arrive to those conclusions....But I am not getting the solution presented in of the other links of the site...Furthermore  , all the solution in the thread is verifying the user's solution and not providing with an actual "detailed" one...
The user in that link asked whether the solution is valid or not...The user specifically ask that he does not need a solution for the problem ...so no solutions are posted in a "direct way" ...al those solutions pertains for a verification purpose of the users solution. But this is not the case here...I am not quite getting the solution posted there either..Its a bit off ...

Comment: "A little off" does not explain what you are looking for.

Comment: @"A little off" umm...ok..I am providing why it seems a little off..please do check the post..Thank you!

Comment: @Ross Millikan...the one asking the question in that link of this site is not asking for a solution but asking the users whether that solution is complete or not...But I do want to know how to do this?

Comment: $(1,2,3)$ is not a solution, so I wouldn't trust much in the book solution.

Comment: @jjagmath That's true...but I need a detailed and complete solution....

Comment: Barry Cipra's answer in this thread linked answers your specific question as to why either at least one of $a,b,c$ must be $2$ or less or all of $a,b,c$ must be $3$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616639/find-all-solutions-of-frac-1-x-frac-1-y-frac-1-z-1