# Find all $a,b,c$ such that that sum of their reciprocals $\ge1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Determine all set of positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge1$$

I don't know why but I can never solve these type of problems completely. I try trial and error for a few minutes and when I don't get any solution for a considerable time period, I assume that no more solutions exist.

From my trial and error, the incomplete solutions that I found are $(2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 4),(3, 3, 3),(2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4)$

How to find the rest of them$?$ And please please tell a generalized approach, as far as possible.

Comment: This has been asked or answered many times online

Comment: For equality there are $10$ solutions, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616639/find-all-solutions-of-frac-1-x-frac-1-y-frac-1-z-1?noredirect=1), and for strict inequality another $3$, see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2447820p20334231).

Comment: What have you tried? I find it difficult to imagine not being able to answer this question, as it is a very simple matter of bounding the search space and then checking a short list of options.

Comment: It should also be obvious that if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then so is $(x,y,z)$ whenever $x\leq a$, $y\leq b$ and $z\leq c$. That immediately shows you that your list is very incomplete, and it should give you a lot more solutions.

Comment: Taking $a=1$ immediately gives infinitely many solutions to the inequality.